# Need help for wrong classification with Artificial Neural Network in R

Tags: r, networking, classification

I am trying to perform classification using neuralnet package in R but quite unexpectedly, all my groups are wrongly classified.
This is my dataset. I call it var and the data is about the principal components derived from geometric morphometric analysis:

```r
var <- structure(list(Comp1 = c(-0.043678009, -0.015762238, -0.030073495, 
0.05375719, 0.043316675, -0.014881289, 0.010244825, -0.008646604, 
0.065330354, 0.039213968, -0.013820042, 0.025893332, -0.029177858, 
-0.005809778, 0.044924654, -0.002819489, 0.044784785, 0.0190347, 
0.030576512, -0.032389669, -0.017554513, 0.012083605, -0.012007563, 
0.082748712, 0.023170057, 0.024499518, 0.002587171, 0.075564288, 
-0.047631694, -0.010968749, 0.05923261, 0.048385878, 0.039056546, 
0.202019055, 0.003103156, 0.059409172, 0.118257139, 0.025757974, 
0.037290582, 0.151418431, -0.009065678, -0.004506414, -0.024237065, 
-0.02794199, 0.045991947, -0.034736678, -0.039498503, 0.033947857, 
-0.040292924, -0.011147239, -0.03401308, 0.046130437, 0.106188231, 
0.033849807, -0.008645721, -0.06116855, 0.049030183, 0.066190233, 
-0.046352599, -0.039752876, 0.022025752, -0.036689669, -0.047919243, 
-0.026952025, -0.041911206, -0.076422909, -0.061433793, -0.072500995, 
-0.09524083, -0.022469157, -0.034556044, -0.05350736, -0.040583637, 
-0.056893199, -0.032591799, -0.059233056, -0.046713239, 0.006786442, 
-0.04141884, -0.03266917, -0.053437174, -0.066860711, -0.04701744, 
-0.038199971), Comp2 = c(0.106197771, 0.038853287, -0.009586194, 
0.01546945, 0.007791027, 0.054085092, 0.029563878, 0.053796422, 
0.014529306, -0.002164454, 0.035410633, -0.003035837, 0.034797658, 
0.035741215, 0.021210839, 0.091083686, 0.031353316, 0.027326734, 
0.021749531, 0.014798023, 0.03651892, 0.027437606, 0.097491939, 
-0.011535327, 0.075210854, 0.047728837, 0.03680191, -0.0019042, 
0.00508926, -0.007091458, -0.015697379, -0.031567993, 0.027575257, 
-0.033472653, 0.028501693, -0.005920578, -0.024424968, 0.004273246, 
0.010612727, -0.005666285, 0.019489735, 0.024529405, 0.068469916, 
0.020681783, -0.050098506, -0.040299041, -0.059710577, -0.044555868, 
0.003098376, -0.005214694, -0.010813529, -0.006359585, -0.030839344, 
-0.012675, -0.016682054, 0.026074561, -0.020378631, -0.048740329, 
0.002417645, 0.00678095, -0.059978291, -0.041674102, -0.021821281, 
-0.055746038, -0.027710355, -0.004917345, 0.023265356, -0.025182319, 
-0.017818901, -0.054027368, -0.055255457, -0.019073468, -0.066790203, 
-0.020698562, -0.061031909, -0.072301103, -0.000459287, 0.004827286, 
-0.020492883, -0.033835589, -0.023829698, -0.023618359, -0.006553752, 
-0.019384373), Comp3 = c(0.019370575, -0.000977504, -0.015949697, 
-0.041675908, 0.003843391, 0.065068385, -0.021773973, 0.029606759, 
0.011182254, -0.033646194, -0.023043307, -0.003194197, -0.004793956, 
-0.013026685, -0.024434824, 0.04953092, 0.00904899, 0.00638971, 
-0.052922732, 0.015380785, 0.020342218, -0.040278196, -0.006765608, 
0.000779358, -0.00778628, 0.015690095, -0.070651064, 0.019125123, 
0.006408219, -0.018649606, -0.03977679, -0.021797813, 0.008856891, 
0.000168104, -0.024670295, 0.009507414, -0.04022888, 0.004622495, 
0.009113227, 0.05444819, 0.018766967, 0.002849717, -0.008992842, 
-0.072379607, 0.040268196, -0.033712899, 0.009162877, 0.044092866, 
-0.018616039, -0.022878386, -0.031386712, -0.014559469, 0.010187616, 
0.023601504, -0.003279511, 0.002901084, 0.068592281, -0.001983248, 
-0.013415314, 0.02766604, 0.014857762, -0.046121839, 0.027316904, 
-0.046386836, -0.009635136, 0.006190401, 0.031518971, -0.005726611, 
-0.000555022, 0.012560026, 0.024600255, -0.01337327, -0.02917823, 
0.018095722, 0.029429293, 0.007912679, 0.048609222, -0.040059428, 
0.039636213, 0.012907316, 0.020420616, -0.012081349, 0.005001785, 
0.024735839), Comp4 = c(-0.005555703, 0.018188554, 0.02052191, 
-0.000958392, -0.060602876, -0.006571146, -0.004723142, 0.008185275, 
-0.027918786, 0.010634161, 0.014053425, 0.011646883, -0.002817306, 
0.005740302, 0.000537051, 0.008316595, -0.004939424, -0.011746872, 
0.006751221, -0.031804693, -0.006489924, 0.036307635, 0.008936219, 
0.003207275, 0.0031718, -0.017391805, -0.030844852, -0.016959765, 
-0.004735194, 0.000341387, -0.013563078, 0.01092632, -0.008092286, 
0.075805568, 0.010390055, -0.046509531, 0.032315348, -0.01898852, 
-0.038681805, 0.04080175, -0.018479673, -0.009872088, 0.017831161, 
0.010496896, -0.038257437, -0.039206638, 0.016592056, 0.004282918, 
-0.019499303, 0.002672155, 0.015857611, -0.025660836, 0.060586559, 
-0.021464783, -0.032251084, -0.010362752, -0.015363808, -0.018290359, 
-0.015329226, 0.02231529, -0.030013975, -0.01740758, 0.017649614, 
-0.020145257, 0.027430923, 0.058448049, 0.043779322, 0.019491138, 
0.043457154, -0.022405624, 0.019172859, 0.025975139, 0.002272588, 
0.051037618, 0.017952296, -0.010134686, 0.003325105, -0.02578557, 
-0.006936403, -0.029928597, -0.003699375, 0.021593396, 0.000379863, 
-0.038988288), Comp5 = c(0.046937867, -0.034863316, -0.027626336, 
-0.039099433, -0.018245965, 0.005869268, -0.023169529, -0.005482171, 
-0.035553081, -0.0124463, -0.00443745, -0.020619724, -0.03134413, 
-0.009100669, 0.01833662, 0.003631552, -0.024177594, -0.030577204, 
-0.003638195, -0.023132407, -0.018570501, -0.004332569, 0.04675734, 
-0.018012229, -0.002478705, -0.034490187, 0.013256907, -0.010100717, 
-0.017158408, -0.006159434, 0.015731279, -0.001686591, 0.009206682, 
0.013298105, -0.017031863, 0.011806824, 0.031890593, 0.003629328, 
0.002456941, -0.014232193, -0.033282555, -0.012896195, 0.025234209, 
-0.006570181, 0.003457926, 0.024580277, 0.019611929, 0.007919515, 
0.025692813, 0.011580604, 0.022041652, 0.011117334, 0.034092609, 
0.010118818, 0.035552605, 0.012519007, 0.030572893, 0.028031283, 
0.015239717, 0.01194325, -0.026551159, 0.016535447, -0.025689035, 
0.019616231, -0.015756123, -0.021134497, 0.027077021, -0.005602731, 
0.033249774, 0.00243281, -0.020890586, -0.017932335, -0.024177742, 
-0.005669424, 0.000853579, -0.019264108, 0.030498064, 0.026802873, 
0.033834347, -0.005118188, -0.010903814, -0.016154091, -0.003845214, 
0.016188992), Comp6 = c(-0.0108, 0.00377, -3.35e-05, 0.00884, 
-0.0478, -0.0301, -0.00463, -0.0243, -0.00737, 0.00107, 0.0111, 
-0.00838, 0.0194, -0.00649, -0.0161, 0.00271, 0.00942, -0.00425, 
0.00453, 0.00701, 0.00101, 0.00857, -0.0293, -0.0303, 0.0179, 
0.000227, -0.00748, -0.0157, 0.00385, 0.00915, -0.0177, 0.026, 
0.0214, -0.0103, 0.0269, 0.0174, -0.0281, -0.0129, -0.00503, 
0.00223, 0.00941, -0.00147, 0.000754, 0.0237, 0.026, -0.0095, 
0.0267, 0.0403, -0.0102, 0.0114, 0.00769, 0.0441, -0.00199, 0.014, 
0.011, 0.0267, 0.00346, 0.051, 0.00504, 0.00145, -0.0274, -0.0107, 
0.015, -0.017, 0.0214, 0.00252, 0.0051, -0.0341, 0.00585, -0.0377, 
0.0147, -0.00165, -0.00846, -0.0279, -0.0505, -0.0101, 7.5e-05, 
-0.0232, 6.85e-05, -0.00344, -0.00417, -0.0121, 0.0158, 0.0226
), Comp7 = c(0.009201054, -0.001000029, 0.001513634, 0.00516057, 
-0.022056798, 0.02150156, 0.013018862, -0.011444344, 0.013858772, 
-0.001821879, 0.025236495, -0.03664023, 0.021054701, 0.0250594, 
-0.010718531, 0.025274822, -0.029914049, 0.007833252, 0.009756311, 
0.017253698, 0.038052011, 0.005564674, -0.000916591, -0.015569467, 
-0.023771289, -0.002698619, -0.012168439, -0.029286223, 0.012257001, 
-0.015006772, 0.025579363, -0.017650463, -0.025166785, 0.024993158, 
-0.018175692, 0.003988543, 0.02588026, -0.042763781, -0.019114973, 
0.01859159, 0.011454256, 0.001082183, -0.025837214, 0.011175081, 
-0.019160056, 0.024037515, -0.000406038, -0.01670672, -0.007125997, 
-0.004049274, -0.008063721, -0.023719539, 0.02509065, -0.011498912, 
0.014545571, 0.019808842, -0.00147822, -0.000355358, -0.01627626, 
-0.006783305, -0.013940259, 0.001824686, 0.004824667, 0.001283487, 
-0.00692154, -0.014572477, -0.009815885, -0.014885659, -0.022430618, 
0.00054368, 0.015712947, -0.019586313, 0.004639409, -0.040717055, 
0.001072833, 0.017385111, 0.002362076, 0.008985181, -0.001059632, 
0.025084909, 0.015465447, 0.020445468, 0.016821464, 0.026999808
), Comp8 = c(-0.029590511, 0.009085306, -0.018121178, -0.031057869, 
0.001162598, 0.009243675, -0.007596605, -0.017850777, -0.00769808, 
-0.02628212, -0.001129508, -0.007142073, 0.032374255, -0.017781299, 
0.012634196, -0.027336887, 0.034375869, 0.015789751, -0.011087085, 
0.008406294, 0.03222381, -0.008764296, -0.014835882, 0.003919117, 
-0.003268376, 0.015631365, 0.006037255, -0.009009668, -0.000562206, 
0.002532623, 0.026632508, -0.00812547, 0.004155069, -0.002332192, 
0.001954712, -0.001744746, 0.032519327, 0.020132252, 0.022837197, 
0.002058128, -0.013950409, -0.002596351, -0.012963283, 0.025673012, 
-0.000244422, 0.006366576, 0.035737658, -0.000323137, 0.009715091, 
-0.002854783, -0.005524501, -0.009337167, -0.012168338, -0.008496056, 
-0.006218181, 0.02150436, 0.001243187, -0.002616929, 0.007675587, 
0.018602901, 0.000749392, 0.01265612, -0.027355524, -0.021671951, 
-0.032111752, 0.022721392, 0.028814882, 0.011742193, -0.009227956, 
-0.006196247, -0.00665508, -0.01806194, -0.016276999, 0.003737314, 
0.009782321, -0.043205867, -0.038543763, -0.024645495, 0.015727442, 
-0.001386234, 0.005034221, 0.030080356, 0.01696678, -0.004286898
), Comp9 = c(0.024124799, 0.010590169, -0.00434102, -0.017651206, 
-0.012065711, 0.003914526, 0.026350056, -0.005874085, 0.002013325, 
0.003284184, -0.007787272, 0.009476176, 0.005608538, -0.015483257, 
-0.006596389, 0.028262033, 0.001395772, -0.008714296, 0.015901302, 
0.011755301, -0.00539248, -0.011588021, -0.003985293, 0.007822877, 
-0.012011498, -0.012765912, -0.017344068, 0.036558631, 0.034789512, 
0.009420331, -0.009878438, -0.023433018, 0.000203699, -0.012501547, 
0.011158631, -0.002470736, 0.027733743, -0.013878949, 0.010963138, 
-0.016726725, -0.00866716, 0.001389092, 0.013785963, 0.01811994, 
0.013569533, 0.005105531, 0.016454122, 0.023782469, 0.016206792, 
0.001039094, 0.008831884, -0.015132206, 0.007125183, -0.023010276, 
0.022028467, 0.018695944, -0.004232689, -0.011540138, -0.010380543, 
0.008572337, 0.026785065, -0.004591672, -0.017698767, 0.013920162, 
0.011865873, -0.02553858, 0.005083493, -0.005585399, -0.003407329, 
-0.000398253, 0.024058366, 0.006451154, 0.013266946, -0.023505517, 
0.014285539, 0.017038241, -0.022849166, -0.044279095, -0.018036641, 
-0.03659091, -0.032924181, -0.013064653, -0.032924728, -0.013940114
), Comp10 = c(-0.011712261, 0.002544151, -0.016857163, 0.005066174, 
0.012317622, -0.004809576, 0.01061714, -0.00210883, 0.018117601, 
0.021506087, -0.011841368, -0.000609867, -0.001379153, 0.009872612, 
0.002322378, 0.021463059, 0.014404503, -0.019255476, -0.005070956, 
0.014503303, -0.007088584, -0.027583013, -0.013737938, 0.032252763, 
-0.001983445, -0.008919937, 0.029191292, -0.00086124, -0.010731492, 
-0.001385862, -0.028897047, 0.001245214, -0.015878951, 0.008064385, 
-0.026559476, 0.009805208, -0.002953512, -0.023015082, -0.00337933, 
0.011141274, -0.011840508, -0.021832031, 0.033319272, -0.008233145, 
-0.013160173, -0.002965348, 0.003668892, -0.02479012, -0.003159175, 
-0.008091592, 0.006983448, 0.020291415, -0.009433116, -0.014969474, 
-0.003374975, 0.025205329, -0.012761968, 0.023154987, -0.005823599, 
0.035167698, -0.013627062, 0.024923807, -0.006822414, 0.012861309, 
-0.01617651, 0.0244749, -0.002392045, -0.006923019, -0.006687047, 
-0.003934253, 0.00208029, -0.018140326, 0.001623518, 0.016734376, 
-0.003648439, 0.009213112, 0.014258155, -0.025396128, -0.011261355, 
0.00019875, 0.007691074, 0.002818133, -0.005239887, 0.018200038
), Group = c("H1", "H1", "H1", "H1", "H1", "H1", "H1", "H1", 
"H1", "H1", "H1", "H1", "H1", "H1", "H1", "H1", "H1", "H1", "H1", 
"H1", "H1", "H1", "H1", "H1", "H1", "H1", "H2", "H2", "H2", "H2", 
"H2", "H2", "H2", "H2", "H2", "H2", "H2", "H2", "H2", "H2", "H2", 
"H2", "H2", "H2", "H3", "H3", "H3", "H3", "H3", "H3", "H3", "H3", 
"H3", "H3", "H3", "H3", "H3", "H3", "H3", "H4", "H4", "H4", "H4", 
"H4", "H4", "H4", "H4", "H4", "H4", "H4", "H4", "H4", "H4", "H4", 
"H4", "H4", "H4", "H4", "H4", "H4", "H4", "H4", "H4", "H4")), row.names = c(NA, 
-84L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

and these are the codes I used for ANN analysis

```r
library(neuralnet)

nn <- neuralnet(Group ~ ., var, hidden = c(5,3))
pred <- compute(nn, var[, c(1:10)])
```

Could anybody help, please?

Comment: How is it wrong? If you look at `apply(pred$net.result, MARGIN = 1, which.max)` all of them are the correct group. Your code above doesn't try to compare `pred` with `var$Group`, so what have you tried that shows you it is wrong?

Comment: Could you please tell me how you changed the code to a structure rapidly? I want to do the same thing.

Comment: You can use `dput(var)` to get that!

Comment: In fact, I changed the names of my groups to post it here. My real names are Horse (H1), Hybrid (H2), Donkey (H3) and Hemione (H4). When I use the real names, the classification is wrong. another question: I want to know the percentage of correct classification with the real names of groups. which code should I use?